# Typed vs typeless language

Tags: types, compiler-construction, programming-languages, declaration

I am learning **C** and assembly language together. I noticed that assembly is a type-less language compared to the **C** which requires declaration of the data type before data can be processed. But also I learnt that even a code written in **C** is first compiled into a code written in assembly and then assembled into object code. So that means data type declaration we use in **C** or any high level language is only meant for the ease of **C** compiler. They don't have any special bearing on the object code. Is that correct?

What I gathered is that type declaration tells compiler what all operations can be done on the data, size of the data (required to store data in data segment), size of the max and min decimal numbers that can be stored. Am I right to say so?

Are there are any other benefits of type declaration?

Comment: quick practical answer: use typeless prog lang for quick stuff, use typed progr lang for complex apps, even if it looks more difficult

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C, we have a simple type system but it's not particular sophisticated, can be (and frequently is, in practice) circumvented with completely unchecked casts, etc. (For these reasons, C is often called "weakly typed", which is ill-defined and usually used for bashing a language, but at least tells that types aren't *that* important.) The size, layout and alignment of types isn't fixed, although it will generally be consistent with the same compiler (version) on the same platform. An `int` may be 14 bits large, etc., these things aren't guaranteed (except that the C standards requires some ordering between the the basic integral types, e.g. `short` must not be larger than `int`).

The programmer doesn't know the details, but the compiler does and in fact needs to. For example, the exact code generated for `foo.y` where `struct Foo { int x; short y; };` and `struct Foo foo;` depends e.g. on the exact sizes of `int` and `short` and on the padding of `struct Foo`, as it compiles down to "take the adress of `foo`, add the offset of `y` in `struct Foo`, and use that". Even the `struct Foo foo;` requires exact knowledge of `struct Foo` (and, recursively, the types it is composed of) - the generated code must know the exact `sizeof(struct Foo)` to reserve the right number of bytes on the stack? Similarily, type declarations are needed to know which opcodes to use for math (`iadd` or `fadd` or addition? Must one of the operands be extended, and to what size?), comparisions, the step size when doing pointer arithmetic (`p + n` actually adds `n * sizeof(*p)`), etc. This also prevents access to nonexistent members (and, by extension, passing values to functions which would then run into this problem - i.e. type mismatch), but that's more like a convenient side effect - the compiler considers it an error because wouldn't know what code to emit, not because it believes programmers are like children that must be watched and kept in order.

In assembly language (usually - just yesterday I read about a project at Microsoft Research that develops a typed, verifyable assembly language for an OS that's safe against certain bugs by construction), you don't really have types. You have bytes. You take N bytes from some location, do some stuff to them, and store them to some location. Yeah, registers are fixed to some word size and some may be intended for special kinds of values (e.g. dedicated floating point registers with 80 or more bits), but basically, you can store anything you like anywhere. Nobody's stopping you from storing 8 bytes somewhere, later reading only the latter 4 bytes and adding them with your loop counter to form an adress to store the return value at.

In other languages, the type system is much stronger while allowing a huge range of extensions that allow higher-level programming, such as abstracting away the exact types (and hence, their layout and typing) and just taking any type that fullfills a certain contract. It allows type signatures such as `[a] -> a`, which is a function taking a list containing *any* kind of value (as long as it's homogenous, e.g. a list of integers, a list of strings, a list of lists of chars, etc.) and returns one of its elements, without "erasing" (e.g. casting to `void *`) the type. (Depending on the implementation, it may actually generate several implementations, each for a single type with a known layout, for performance - but that doesn't leak through to the programmer.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot that can be said about types and their value for programming. And what you see in C is not even the tip of the iceberg. Rather, it's a dirty snow ball that somebody dumped on the tip of the tip of the iceberg. :) The first couple of pages in the following classic paper explain a few of the basic merits of type systems:

http://www.lucacardelli.name/Papers/TypeSystems.pdf

Let me just add two things.

First, there is a difference between a language being typed, and requiring (explicit) type declarations. Some modern languages, especially from the functional camp, have sophisticated type systems that yet don't require you to write down a single type most of the time. All types are inferred by the compiler.

Second, a type system essentially is a logic. A logic that expresses certain properties of a program, which then get checked by the compiler. In principle, there is no limit to how powerful this logic can be made. C is an extremely boring example. On the other end of the spectrum are languages where you can e.g. express the type of sorted lists, and the type of a sorting function, so that the function only type-checks if it actually is a correct implementation of a sorting algorithm. Obviously, it is immensely useful if the compiler can actually check correctness of your program like that. However, there is a trade-off between expressiveness of a type system and ease of use, so in practice, most mainstream languages end up on the simplistic side. But special domains sometimes benefit from more sophisticated type systems enormously.

Here is a recent article in CACM discussing (among other things) the advantages of the type system found in the functional language OCaml:

http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2011/11/138203-ocaml-for-the-masses/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've pretty much nailed it. Typing is just a handy abstraction. What matters is how you use the raw bits. Typing helps to force you to use those bits in the intended way.

*Update*

In a way, it helps ensure the correctness of your program by eliminating some common errors.
Let's say you had two variables, `char var1 = 'a'` and `int var2 = 10;`. If you accidentally tried to add `var1 + var2`, a typed language may generate an error. If it wasn't typed, it might happily give you the result of `107` and keep going. It might be difficult to track down where `107` comes from, until you realize that the ASCII representation of `a` is 97.

So in one regard, yes, it ensures correctness of your program. But there are obviously many other errors (logical errors and the like) which cannot be prevented or identified by typing alone.

Comment: so data type declarations of a high level language are equivalent of directives of assembly language. they help the compiler but does not get translated into the machine code.. Am I correct to say so?

Comment: @Saurabh That sounds about right, but I honestly don't know enough about assembler (specifically directives) to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

OR....

A more sophisticated typeless language might give you the result

```
'a' + 7
```

which may not be an error at all depending upon the definiton of the "+"  operator.

Comment: The C language also defines the result of `'a' + 7`.

Comment: Yes, and also the value of "a"+7 and 7+"a" and "a"+'a'. Tricky thing, C.